# Pure CSS Solution for reordering divs

Tags: html, css

I need a pure CSS solution for reorganizing some divs so that they stack in a different order. I'd rather not use JS for this, nor do any DOM manipulation as I'm building this page with React.js.

Can anyone think of how to order the following divs:

```
<div id="slide0"></div>
<div id="slide1"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
<div id="slide-right0"></div>
<div id="slide-right1"></div>
<div id="slide-right2"></div>
```

So that they resemble the following order:

```
<div id="slide0"></div>
<div id="slide-right0"></div>
<div id="slide1"></div>
<div id="slide-right1"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
<div id="slide-right2"></div>
```

This is of course when I don't know how many divs there will be. For now there are 11 sections but there may be more or fewer in the future.

***EDIT** I'm using Sass and so I have the option to use loops, etc. An ideal solution would be to run some logic that can do this for any number of divs when the number of divs is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```css
.div-container {
      display: flex; //set display as flex
      flex-direction: column; //Set display direction as vertical (ascending order in this case)
      //prefixes in case you need to prefix it. 
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    }
    
    #slide0 {
      order: 1 //set order of selected div.
       //prefixes in case you need to prefix it. 
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -webkit-order: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
    }
    
    #slide-right0 {
      order: 2;
    }
    
    #slide1 {
      order: 3;
    }
    
    #slide-right1 {
      order: 4;
    }
    
    #slide2 {
      order: 5;
    }
    
    #slide-right2 {
      order: 6;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
  <div id="slide0">Slide0</div>
  <div id="slide1">slide1</div>
  <div id="slide2">slide2</div>
  <div id="slide-right0">slide-right0</div>
  <div id="slide-right1">slide-right1</div>
  <div id="slide-right2">slide-right2</div>
</div>
```

For cases like this it would be nice if you were to use some kind of template using [jade](https://github.com/pugjs/jade) or [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/), etc. so that you can use for loops etc. and not have to code everything yourself.

Comment: I'm using Sass, are there any options that would allow me to do this kind of operation when the number of divs is unknown using some kind of loop?

Comment: yes there is.. i dont normally use such things, but you could check out his [link](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) and see if you can figure it out..

Answer (score 4):

Used to **[flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** property

define your parent div `display` `flex`  and `flex-direction` `column`

as like this i just create a demo

```css
#div > div {
    border: 1px solid  red;
}

#div {
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column;    
}
#slide0 {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -moz-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
#slide-right0 {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -moz-order: 2;
    box-order: 2;
}
#slide1 {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    -moz-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
#slide-right1 {
    -webkit-order: 4;
    -moz-order: 4;
    order: 4;
}
#slide2 {
    -webkit-order: 5;
    -moz-order: 5;
    order: 5;
}
#slide-right2 {
    -webkit-order: 6;
    -moz-order: 6;
    order: 6;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
    



<div id="slide0">Slide0</div>
<div id="slide1">slide1</div>
<div id="slide2">slide2</div>
<div id="slide-right0">slide-right0</div>
<div id="slide-right1">slide-right1</div>
<div id="slide-right2">slide-right2</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Your example is using the old flex specification, which is [obsolete](https://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) and unreliable. Use the new `display: flex` option [like I have made in this example](http://jsbin.com/yitovesido/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam you're right; I guess if you are wanting to support outdated browsers there's [benefit in using both](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)?

Comment: @Quoid - I thought you were the author of this answer, oops. But you're right :) That could work if required.

Comment: Thank you @rohit-azad, I need to catch for all cases where the number of divs is unknown. Seeing my edit in the question, can you think of any Sass-enabled options that might allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hqya7q6o/128/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="flex">
   <div id="slide0">1</div>
   <div id="slide1">2</div>
   <div id="slide2">3</div>
   <div id="slide-right0">4</div>
   <div id="slide-right1">5</div>
   <div id="slide-right2">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#flex { display: flex;flex-direction: column; }
#flex > #slide0 { order: 1; }
#flex > #slide1 { order: 3; }
#flex > #slide2 { order: 5; }
#flex > #slide-right0 { order: 2; }
#flex > #slide-right1 { order: 4; }
#flex > #slide-right2 { order: 6; }
```

Comment: Thank you @arun-kumar-m, please see the edit in my question regarding using Sass to account for cases where the number of divs is unknown.